# Indenting multiple files

Tags: vim, indentation

I want to indent multiple files which are poorly indented and indent them properly as would vim do when I type `gg=G`. 
Is there someway to enter the `=` command or its alias in the command mode? i.e after a `:`?
If that is possible I can use the bufdo command like in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12523/how-to-do-a-text-replacement-in-a-big-folder-hierarchy) question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run any normal command with `:normal`, e.g. `:normal =G`.

If the files are C source code, it may be easier to use the external program [`indent`](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/).

Comment: I recomment astyle over indent.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to do it with vim, but should be possible.

You may also try the command "indent", it should do what you want, although not with the indentation you have configured in vim.