# Make sed ask for confirmation before each replacement?

Tags: vim, sed

Is there a way to make sed ask me for confirmation before each replace? Something similar to 'c' when using replace inside vim.

Does sed do this at all?

Comment: It would be technically possible but more of an intellectual exercise than a useful endeavor. See [How to do a text replacement in a big folder hierarchy?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12523) which has Vim and Perl solutions.

Comment: I *am* using vim (args and argdo) whenever I need 'confirmation', but was wondering if there was a 'simpler' way

Comment: It goes against the basic purpose of sed - to automate editing over a stream.

Comment: @teppic not really because you would still have to *go find* the instances in text files, which sed can do for you. I think the question makes sense, just in case you added the wrong files to a list and wanted to see what file you were editing

Answer (score 48):

Doing it with `sed` would probably not be possible as it's a non-interactive stream editor.  Wrapping `sed` in a script would require far too much thinking. It is easier to just do it with `vim`:

```
vim -c '%s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/gc' -c 'wq' file.in
```

---

Since it was mentioned in comments below, here's how this would be used on multiple files matching a particular filename globbing pattern in the current directory:

```
for fname in file*.txt; do
    vim -c '%s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/gc' -c 'wq' "$fname"
done
```

Or, if you first want to make sure that the file really contains a line that matches the given pattern first, before performing the substitution,

```
for fname in file*.txt; do
    grep -q 'PATTERN' "$fname" &&
    vim -c '%s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/gc' -c 'wq' "$fname"
done
```

The above two shell loops modified into `find` commands that do the same things but for all files with a particular name somewhere in or under some `top-dir` directory,

```
find top-dir -type f -name 'file*.txt' \
    -exec vim -c '%s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/gc' -c 'wq' {} \;
```

```
find top-dir -type f -name 'file*.txt' \
    -exec grep -q 'PATTERN' {} \; \
    -exec vim -c '%s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/gc' -c 'wq' {} \;
```

Or, using the original shell loops and having `find` feed pathnames into them:

```
find top-dir -type f -name 'file*.txt' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        vim -c "%s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/gc" -c "wq" "$pathname"
    done' sh {} +
```

```
find top-dir -type f -name 'file*.txt' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        grep -q "PATTERN" "$pathname" &&
        vim -c "%s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/gc" -c "wq" "$pathname"
    done' sh {} +
```

You do, in any case, *not* want to do something like `for filename in $( grep -rl ... )` since

1. it would require that `grep` finishes running before even starting the first iteration of loop, which is *inelegant*, and
2. the pathnames returned by `grep` would be split into words on whitespaces, and these words would undergo filename globbing (this disqualifies pathnames that contains spaces and special characters).

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Comment: The advantage to `sed` is it can operate on multiple files, e.g., `sed -i 's/old/new/g' /path/to/*.txt` or something similar.

Comment: `for i in $(grep -rl "old"); do vim -c "%s/old/new/gc" -c "wq" "$i"; done`

Comment: @tecepe, please convert it to an answer, Thank You.

Comment: @Nishant It would be a fragile answer as it would disqualify any file containing whitespace in its name or path.

Comment: If you don't want to open and close vim a whole bunch, do the entire operation in vim with `vim $(grep -RIlZ 'pattern')` then in vim use `:bufdo %s/pattern/replace/gce | update`

Answer (score 8):

You can get this by doing such:

```
:%s/OLD_TEXT/NEW_TEXT/gc
```

Specifically, adding the `c` after the third delimiter.

Note that the 'c' option only works in Vim; you won't be able to use it with `sed` at the command line.

Comment: To clarify: this only works in Vim, not regular command line `sed`.

Comment: The OP is tagged with `vim`, so this answer is applicable; though, clearly vim and sed have different abilities

Answer (score 4):

You could let `sed` do its thing on the file and then save the result to a temporary file which you can then interactively patch into the original file using `sdiff` (see http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#Invoking-sdiff):

```bash
sed -r 's/something/something_else/g' my_file > tmp_file
sdiff -o my_file -s -d my_file tmp_file
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to open and close vim a whole bunch as other answers suggest, you can do the entire operation in vim...

1: open all files containing your pattern:

```
vim $(grep -RIlZ 'pattern')
```

2) in vim replace your pattern in all open buffers (with confirmation):

```
:bufdo %s/pattern/replace/gce | update
```

These can even be combined like so

```
vim $(grep -RIlZ 'pattern') -c ':bufdo %s/pattern/replace/gce | update'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
searchandreplace () {
if [ -z $2 ] ; then
    realpath * | xargs grep -ins --directories=skip --color=always "$1" | nl -s "."
else
    realpath * | xargs grep -ins --directories=skip --color=always "$1" | nl -s "."
    exp=$(realpath * | xargs grep -ins --directories=skip --color=never "$1" | cut -d':' -f1,2 | awk -F':' '{print $2 $1}' | sed -E "s|^[0-9]+|sed -i \'&s/|; s|//|/"$1"/"$2"/g\' /|")
    IFS=$'\n'
    for d in $exp
        do
        read -p "Exec $(echo -e -n "\033[1;31m$d\033[0m")? " -e REP
            if [ "$REP" = y ]; then
            echo `bash -c $d`;
            fi
    done
fi
}
```

If you feed this with single argument –`searchandreplace "AAA"`– it only searches for that string in the current directory, but if you feed it with double arguments –`searchandreplace AAA BBB`– then in addition to the above it also asks you to replace the first with the second "line by line" for every line.